# Make one method from two pieces of code with continue and return operators?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The same code pieces in five methods are:

```
fooFunction(data: any, path: string): Number {
    let result = 0;
    let decimalCount = 0;
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('length')) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let curItem = data[i];
            let curVal = this.getData(curItem, path); //the same code
            if (curVal == null)//the same code 
                continue; //here I should iterate further
            let curValDecimalCount = this.countDecimals(curVal); //the same code
            if (decimalCount < curValDecimalCount) { //the same code
                decimalCount = curValDecimalCount; //the same code
            } //the same code
            result = Number(curVal/2); //the same code
        }
    } else {
        let curVal = this.getData(data, path); //the same code
        if (curVal == null)//the same code
            return result; //here I should return null value
        let curValDecimalCount = this.countDecimals(curVal); //the same code
        if (decimalCount < curValDecimalCount) { //the same code
            decimalCount = curValDecimalCount; //the same code
        } //the same code
        result = Number(curVal/2); //the same code
    }
    return Number((result);
}
```

Is it possible to take the repeating pieces and put in new method to avoid repeating?

I am struggling with `continue` keyword when method goes into loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this code is correct? The variable `decimalCount` seems to have no use.

Also:

```
fooFunction(data: any, path: string): Number {
    let result = 0;
    let decimalCount = 0;
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('length')) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            result = fooFunction(data[i], path);
        }
    } else {
        let curVal = this.getData(data, path); //the same code
        if (curVal == null)//the same code
            return result; //here I should return null value
        let curValDecimalCount = this.countDecimals(curVal); //the same code
        if (decimalCount < curValDecimalCount) { //the same code
            decimalCount = curValDecimalCount; //the same code
        } //the same code
        result = Number(curVal/2); //the same code
    }
    return Number((result);
}

This is equivalent, unless data is a nested array.

Or:

fooFunction(data: any, path: string): Number {
    let result = 0;
    let decimalCount = 0;
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('length')) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let temp = barFunction(data[i], path);
            if(temp == null) continue;
            result = temp;
        }
    } else {
        result = barFunction(data, path);
    }
    return Number((result);
}

function barFunction(data: any, path: string): Number {
    let curVal = this.getData(data, path); //the same code
        if (curVal == null)//the same code
            return result; //here I should return null value
        let curValDecimalCount = this.countDecimals(curVal); //the same code
        if (decimalCount < curValDecimalCount) { //the same code
            decimalCount = curValDecimalCount; //the same code
        } //the same code
        return Number(curVal/2); //the same code

}
```

Comment: upvoted. Is it possible to refactor without recursion?

Comment: Yes, make a separate function of the shared code and call it on both occasions.

Comment: could you post code, please?

Comment: editted (untested)